# How to check if current time has ongoing events in Calendar in Android?

Tags: android, events, calendar

I have tried querying events from Android Calendar for just after current time, for example

```
    mCursor = getContentResolver().query(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, COLS, 
            CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART + " > " + (new Date()).getTime() +
            " AND " + CalendarContract.Events.ALL_DAY + " = " + 0 +
            " AND " + CalendarContract.Events.DTEND + " - " + CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART + " = " + (1000*60*60*12) ,
            null, CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART);
```

But that result include only one-timed event. I need also every types of events those are occur. So, I thought of checking just a way to check if is current time having ongoing events, and I also need references of them to retrieve title and description and other ongoing events parameters.

Thank you a lot. (my first time here)